# solidus_searchkick - undefined method `deep_symbolize_keys'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, searchkick, solidus

I am using Solidus and I want to implement a better search wiht elasticsearch, I'm using solidus_searchkick to do that. But I get the following error:

```
undefined method 'deep_symbolize_keys' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x0000556eae99cda8>
```

At Spree::HomeController#index, that has:

```
Spree::HomeController.class_eval do
    def index
        @searcher = build_searcher(params.merge(include_images: true))
        @products = @searcher.retrieve_products
        @taxonomies = Spree::Taxonomy.includes(root: :children)
    end
end
```

I have NOT changed anything at Solidus' search options.

I get this error right after I run 'bundle install', installs everything just fine.
Then, I run 'rails s' and I get this error when I try to get my home or any other page that shows me any product.

---

Versions:

- Rails: **5.1.6**
- Ruby: **2.5.1**
- solidus_searchkick: **0.3.4**
- Solidus: **2.5.0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with the deprecated method `deep_symbolize_keys` in Rails 5.1.  I just submitted a Pull Request for the solidus_searchkick gem.  You can find it here https://github.com/elevatorup/solidus_searchkick/pull/6/files

If you point your solidus_searchkick gem to that branch it will work.